# arecord generating blank files

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I am trying to record something using the utility arecord but I am unable to do so.
The command generates an audio file but when I play it, it is blank.

The operating system Information:

```
Linux Network 3.2.0-54-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:08:42 UTC 2013 x86_64 
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

The output of `arecord -l`:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The Screenshot of alsamixer I am linking:

[image]

I am on this since yesterday and have not found any solution. Can my sound card be faulty? I am able to listen to other music files though.

The command I am executing is `arecord -d10 test.wav`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable the capture channel that you're using (in alsamixer, press <kbd>Space</kbd> on `Capture` or `Capture 1`).